# Variable Context Switching Time

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

I just made some changes to the context switch routine of Linux. I am facing now the following dilemma: The context switching time is no longer deterministic, i.e. the execution time varies on the applications that are switched out.

I am wondering now what could be the negative implications of such a behaviour. One potential pitfall I have identified are Real Time Applications. When I have non-constant times for performing the context switches, I assume that is not really ideal. Are there any other issues that need to be considered?

Comment: Hmm, why would you do that? The O(1) scheduler was such a big deal, so  there should be some very compelling reason to break it. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Music and video players can have too big jitter with such scheduler.